# StreamingResponseBody throws exception

Tags: java, spring, exception, stream

I am using StreamingResponseBody to write to output stream. However under load tests,I am seeing few exceptions:

```
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.http.HttpExchangeTracer$FilteredTraceableResponse.includedHeader(HttpExchangeTracer.java:167)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:174)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)  
"java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.http.HttpExchangeTracer.lambda$getHeadersIfIncluded$1(HttpExchangeTracer.java:101)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)".
```

Here is the code:Am I missing anything here?

```
 @GetMapping(value = ID_PATH_PARAM_MAPPING + PDF_PATH)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get", notes = "Fetch pdf")
    @ApiImplicitParams({
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = ID_PATH_PARAM, value = "Id", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "path")})
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getSalePdfByToken(@PathVariable(ID_PATH_PARAM) String eSaleId) {
        PdfDomain pdfResponse = service.getPdf(Id);
        StreamingResponseBody responseBody = getStreamingResponseBody(pdfResponse);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
                .body(responseBody);
    }

    private StreamingResponseBody getStreamingResponseBody(PdfDomain pdfResponse) {            
        return outputStream -> {
            int numberOfBytesToWrite;
            byte[] data = new byte[scsAppConfig.getChunkSize()];
            while ((numberOfBytesToWrite = pdfResponse.getResponse().read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                log.debug("action=getSalePdfByToken; message=writing bytes..;");
                outputStream.write(data, 0, numberOfBytesToWrite);
            }
            pdfResponse.getResponse().close();
        };
    }
```

My async config

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config.async")
@EnableAsync
@Log4j2
@Getter
@Setter
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    private final String THREAD_NAME_PREFIX = "Async_Service_Pool";

    private int corePoolSize = 10;
    private int maxPoolSize = 25;
    private int queueCapacity = 100;
    private long defaultTimeOut = 20000;


    @Bean(name = "asyncTaskExecutor")
    public AsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor(AsyncDecorator asyncDecorator) {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix(THREAD_NAME_PREFIX);
        executor.setCorePoolSize(getCorePoolSize());
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(getMaxPoolSize());
        executor.setQueueCapacity(getQueueCapacity());
        executor.setTaskDecorator(asyncDecorator);
        executor.initialize();
        log.info("AsyncConfig; action=asyncTaskExecutor; state=start; message=\"started executor\"; threadNamePrefix={}; corePoolSize={}; maxPoolSize={}; queueCapacity={}\";",
                executor.getThreadNamePrefix(), corePoolSize, maxPoolSize, queueCapacity);
        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurerConfigurer(AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor, CallableProcessingInterceptor callableProcessingInterceptor) {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
                configurer.setDefaultTimeout(getDefaultTimeOut()).setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
                configurer.registerCallableInterceptors(callableProcessingInterceptor);
                WebMvcConfigurer.super.configureAsyncSupport(configurer);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public CallableProcessingInterceptor callableProcessingInterceptor() {
        return new TimeoutCallableProcessingInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public <T> Object handleTimeout(NativeWebRequest request, Callable<T> task) throws Exception {
                log.error("action=handleTimeout; state=error; message=\"timeout occurred\";");
                return super.handleTimeout(request, task);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reformat your question

Comment: Updating the question with complete stacktrace would also help

Comment: I only have this much stack trace. It starts writing bytes and all of a sudden throws one of these errors

Comment: It only happens very few times

Comment: Those are from actuator endpoints not your code (see the package `org.springframework.boot.actuate` in the stacktraces. Not sure if there is anything you can do about it. One thing I would suggest is to use `StreamUtils.copy` (from Spring) instead of your `while` loop to copy the content to the output stream or at least call `outputStream.flush` after your while loop.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have   "pdfResponse.getResponse().close();" which closed the input stream. Also, if it is from actuator endpoint why it shoes up as part of this api while writing to output stream?

Comment: How does my comment relate to the inputstream? I clearly mention flushing the outputstream!. Actuator registers the request using a filter, so it can obtain information on the request.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum for clarifying. After adding outputstream.flush(), I am getting different nullpointerexception error at ````at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:581)
 at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:117)````

Comment: It resolved the issue for me after I disabled httptracing